# What are the steps to uninstall and reinstall torchvision to match PyTorch's CUDA version?

Tags: pip, pytorch, torchvision

I have this error :

> RuntimeError: Detected that PyTorch and torchvision were compiled with different CUDA versions. PyTorch has CUDA Version=11.7 and torchvision has CUDA Version=11.8. Please reinstall the torchvision that matches your PyTorch install.

What are the commands to de-install and reinstall torchvision?
What is the right version of torchvision I should install?

I tried this :

```
pip uninstall torch -y
```

And then reinstall Pytorch but I always have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

with "nvidia-smi" you can find out your installed CUDA Version
On
https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/
you will find torchvision versions, which fit to your CUDA Version

Comment: nvidia-smi doesn't show you the installed cuda version, it shows the highest-supported cuda version. in order to check which cuda version you have installed you should:
1. cd /usr/local
2. ls -la
The